# want to push the data from images alt to another div according to Active Class

Tags: javascript, html, css

Here are **five columns** in the body part, named **single, double, number pair, all pair, and alphabet pair,** and **four chips** below.Every chip has it's value in the **"alt"** attribute. When we click any of these chips, I want to push that value(alt) to the `"chipMoney`" and it will only show when the columns have the `"activeBet"` class. If there's no active class in the columns, then the value from the chips images **"alt"** attribute will not appear in `"chipMoney"`. Only the chips image **"alt"** value will be added to the `"chipMoney"` when the columns of this `"chipMoney"` have the `"activeBet"` class.

> If the second column has the `"activeBet"` class, then the value will
> be displayed in the "chipMoney"; if the third column has the
> `"activeBet"` class, the value will be shown there. That means only
> the value will be shown in the "activeBet" class; other classes will
> be empty.

```js
let selectChipsDiv = document.getElementById("selected-chips");
//All items declared in a single object
const allChips = [
  {
    name: "1",
    img: "https://i.im.ge/2022/11/28/S0jFH4.image.png",
  },
  {
    name: "50",
    img: "https://i.im.ge/2022/11/28/S0j11C.image.png",
  },
  {
    name: "1000",
    img: "https://i.im.ge/2022/11/28/S0j2wq.image.png",
  },
  {
    name: "5",
    img: "https://i.im.ge/2022/11/28/S0jSZp.image.png",
  },
];

let data = "";
allChips.map((value, key) => {
  data += `
  <img src="${value.img}" alt="${value.name}"/>  
    `;
}, "");
selectChipsDiv.innerHTML = data;

// active class for bet selection
var activeDiv = document.getElementById("SlctBetActvClsDiv");
var activeClass = activeDiv.getElementsByClassName("SlctBetActvCls");

for (var i = 0; i < activeClass.length; i++) {
  activeClass[i].addEventListener("click", function () {
    var current = document.getElementsByClassName("activeBet");
    current[0].className = current[0].className.replace(" activeBet", "");
    this.className += " activeBet";
  });
}
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-family: "Arial Regular";
}

body {
  width: 100%;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  color: #fff;
  background: #400df0;
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center center;
  height: 100vh;
}
body img {
  width: 100%;
}
body button {
  background: transparent;
  border: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.mainimg img {
  -o-object-fit: cover;
  object-fit: cover;
}

.activeBet .snglimg .mdlsc {
  display: block;
}

.snglimg {
  position: relative;
}
.snglimg .mdlsc {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: -9px;
  display: none;
}
.snglimg button {
  width: 95%;
  margin: auto;
}
.snglimg button .btnimg {
  position: relative;
}
.snglimg button .btnimg span {
  position: absolute;
  top: 39%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  color: #fff;
}

.clsebtn img {
  width: 120px;
}

.mdlsc {
  margin-left: 8px;
}

.grypnk {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
  gap: 10px;
  padding: 18px 5px;
  width: 80%;
  margin: auto;
}
.grypnk img {
  width: 100%;
}

.wrapper {
  width: 62%;
  margin: auto;
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: space-between;
  padding: 11px 0px 40px;
}
.wrapper img {
  -o-object-fit: cover;
  object-fit: cover;
}
.wrapper .mainimg {
  width: 90%;
  margin: auto;
}
.wrapper .mainimg .mngrd {
  margin-top: 13px;
  margin-bottom: 12px;
}
.wrapper .mainimg .mngrd .mdlsc {
  top: 81%;
  margin-left: 2px;
}

.coinsc {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  width: 85%;
  margin: auto;
  gap: 8px;
  justify-content: center;
  margin: 10px auto;
}

.coin {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(4, 1fr);
  gap: 5px;
  align-items: center;
}

@media screen and (min-width: 668px) {
  main {
    width: 650px;
    margin: auto;
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
    <link
      rel="stylesheet"
      href="https://static.staticsave.com/naymurcss/responsive.css"
    />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./css/style.css" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <main>
      <section class="wrapper">
        <div>
          <div class="mainimg">
            <div class="row" id="SlctBetActvClsDiv">
              <div class="col-6 SlctBetActvCls activeBet">
                <div class="snglimg">
                  <img
                    src="https://i.im.ge/2022/11/29/SweLxm.dfojdf.png"
                    alt=""
                    class="betActiveImg"
                  />
                  <div class="mdlsc">
                    <button class="opnBtn">
                      <div class="btnimg">
                        <img
                          src="https://i.im.ge/2022/11/29/Swem9L.prctg.png"
                          alt=""
                        />
                        <span class="chipMoney"></span>
                      </div>
                    </button>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="col-6 SlctBetActvCls">
                <div class="snglimg">
                  <img
                    src="https://i.im.ge/2022/11/29/Swew8G.wertedsfsd.png"
                    alt=""
                    class="betActiveImg"
                  />
                  <div class="mdlsc">
                    <button class="opnBtn">
                      <div class="btnimg">
                        <img
                          src="https://i.im.ge/2022/11/29/Swem9L.prctg.png"
                          alt=""
                        />
                        <span class="chipMoney"></span>
                      </div>
                    </button>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="col-4 SlctBetActvCls">
                <div class="snglimg mngrd">
                  <img
                    src="https://i.im.ge/2022/11/29/SweNQx.dsfd.png"
                    alt=""
                    class="betActiveImg"
                  />
                  <div class="mdlsc">
                    <button class="opnBtn">
                      <div class="btnimg">
                        <img
                          src="https://i.im.ge/2022/11/29/Swem9L.prctg.png"
                          alt=""
                        />
                        <span id="chipMoney"></span>
                      </div>
                    </button>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="col-4 SlctBetActvCls">
                <div class="snglimg mngrd">
                  <img
                    src="https://i.im.ge/2022/11/29/SwetxJ.allpair.png"
                    alt=""
                    class="betActiveImg"
                  />
                  <div class="mdlsc">
                    <button class="opnBtn">
                      <div class="btnimg">
                        <img
                          src="https://i.im.ge/2022/11/29/Swem9L.prctg.png"
                          alt=""
                        />
                        <span class="chipMoney"></span>
                      </div>
                    </button>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="col-4 SlctBetActvCls">
                <div class="snglimg mngrd">
                  <img
                    src="https://i.im.ge/2022/11/29/SweCqS.alphabet.png"
                    alt=""
                    class="betActiveImg"
                  />
                  <div class="mdlsc">
                    <button class="opnBtn">
                      <div class="btnimg">
                        <img
                          src="https://i.im.ge/2022/11/29/Swem9L.prctg.png"
                          alt=""
                        />
                        <span class="chipMoney"></span>
                      </div>
                    </button>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="coinsc">
          <div class="coin" id="selected-chips"></div>
        </div>
      </section>
    </main>

    <script src="./js/script.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: What's the problem/where are you stuck?

Comment: I want the active columns to get the value from chips images when we click any of the chips image.

Comment: Is there anyone who can give me this solution?

Comment: Please don't delete questions then ask the same question - better/best to update the original question to add any additional clarity

Comment: You might also re-visit some of your older questions to add clarity on why the proposed answers did/do not work for you as you appear to have a good percentage where you have not accepted any answers - we are glad to help as long as we have a clear description of your challenge.

Answer (score 0):

I think I understood your question requirements (perhaps) but found one little mistake (?). Within the `NUMBER PAIR` portion of HTML you had `<span id="chipMoney"></span>` but I think that should be `<span class="chipMoney"></span>`?

With that said perhaps the following is what you were trying to accomplish?

FYI: I added the bright colours in CSS to identify the regions more clearly only

```js
let selectChipsDiv = document.getElementById("selected-chips");
let active = document.getElementById("SlctBetActvClsDiv");
let col = document.querySelectorAll('.SlctBetActvCls');
let stake=1;

const allChips = [{
    name: "1",
    img: "//i.im.ge/2022/11/28/S0jFH4.image.png",
  },
  {
    name: "50",
    img: "//i.im.ge/2022/11/28/S0j11C.image.png",
  },
  {
    name: "1000",
    img: "//i.im.ge/2022/11/28/S0j2wq.image.png",
  },
  {
    name: "5",
    img: "//i.im.ge/2022/11/28/S0jSZp.image.png",
  },
];

allChips.forEach(obj => {
  let oImg = new Image();
      oImg.src = obj.img;
      oImg.alt = obj.name;
      oImg.className='chip';
  selectChipsDiv.append(oImg)
});

// classnames used in javascript
const css = {
  active: 'activeBet',
  img: 'betActiveImg',
  container: 'SlctBetActvCls',
  chip:'chip',
  money:'chipMoney'
};

// set the display of the default stake value in the initially active slot
document.querySelector(`.${css.active} span.${css.money}`).textContent=stake;

// assign delegated listener to the wrapper object
document.querySelector('main > .wrapper').addEventListener('click', e => {
  let el = e.target;
  
  // if the click was on an element that is NOT the delegated object (ie: a child of it)
  // process the event to find out more.
  if (el != e.currentTarget) {
    // click originates within 1 of the 5 "bet" type DIV elements
    // or on a child element of such.
    if (
      el.classList.contains(css.container) ||
      el.parentNode.classList.contains(css.container) ||
      el.classList.contains(css.img)
    ) {
    
      if (el instanceof HTMLImageElement) {
        el=el.closest(`div.${css.container}`);
      }
      // clear the "activeBet" class from all elements
      col.forEach(n => n.classList.remove(css.active));
      // add "activeBet" to current element that invoked the event
      el.classList.add(css.active);
      
      // set the "stake" amount in the respective SPAN element
      if( stake )el.querySelector(`span.${css.money}`).textContent=stake;
    }
    
    
    // if the element is one of the "stake" amount images...
    if( el instanceof HTMLImageElement && el.className==css.chip ){
      let span=document.querySelector(`div.${css.container}.${css.active} span.${css.money}`);
      if( span ){
        stake=Number(el.alt);
        span.textContent=stake;
      }
    }
  }
})
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-family: "Arial Regular";
}

.SlctBetActvCls {
  border: 5px solid yellow;
  background: lime;
}

body {
  width: 100%;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  color: #000000;
  background: #400df0;
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center center;
  height: 100vh;
}

body img {
  width: 100%;
}

body button {
  background: transparent;
  border: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.mainimg img {
  -o-object-fit: cover;
  object-fit: cover;
}

.activeBet .snglimg .mdlsc {
  display: block;
}

.snglimg {
  position: relative;
}

.snglimg .mdlsc {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: -9px;
  display: none;
}

.snglimg button {
  width: 95%;
  margin: auto;
}

.snglimg button .btnimg {
  position: relative;
}

.snglimg button .btnimg span {
  position: absolute;
  top: 39%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  color: #fff;
}

.clsebtn img {
  width: 120px;
}

.mdlsc {
  margin-left: 8px;
}

.grypnk {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
  gap: 10px;
  padding: 18px 5px;
  width: 80%;
  margin: auto;
}

.grypnk img {
  width: 100%;
}

.wrapper {
  width: 62%;
  margin: auto;
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: space-between;
  padding: 11px 0px 40px;
}

.wrapper img {
  -o-object-fit: cover;
  object-fit: cover;
}

.wrapper .mainimg {
  width: 90%;
  margin: auto;
}

.wrapper .mainimg .mngrd {
  margin-top: 13px;
  margin-bottom: 12px;
}

.wrapper .mainimg .mngrd .mdlsc {
  top: 81%;
  margin-left: 2px;
}

.coinsc {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  width: 85%;
  margin: auto;
  gap: 8px;
  justify-content: center;
  margin: 10px auto;
}

.coin {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(4, 1fr);
  gap: 5px;
  align-items: center;
}

@media screen and (min-width: 668px) {
  main {
    width: 650px;
    margin: auto;
  }
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://static.staticsave.com/naymurcss/responsive.css" />
<main>
  <section class="wrapper">
    <div>
      <div class="mainimg">
        <div class="row" id="SlctBetActvClsDiv">
        
        
          <!-- SINGLE -->
          <div class="col-6 SlctBetActvCls activeBet">
            <div class="snglimg">
              <img src="https://i.im.ge/2022/11/29/SweLxm.dfojdf.png" alt="" class="betActiveImg" />
              <div class="mdlsc">
                <button class="opnBtn">
                  <div class="btnimg">
                    <img src="https://i.im.ge/2022/11/29/Swem9L.prctg.png" alt="" />
                    <span class="chipMoney"></span>
                  </div>
                </button>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          
          
          <!-- DOUBLE -->
          <div class="col-6 SlctBetActvCls">
            <div class="snglimg">
              <img src="https://i.im.ge/2022/11/29/Swew8G.wertedsfsd.png" alt="" class="betActiveImg" />
              <div class="mdlsc">
                <button class="opnBtn">
                  <div class="btnimg">
                    <img src="https://i.im.ge/2022/11/29/Swem9L.prctg.png" alt="" />
                    <span class="chipMoney"></span>
                  </div>
                </button>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          
          
          <!-- NUMBER PAIR -->
          <div class="col-4 SlctBetActvCls">
            <div class="snglimg mngrd">
              <img src="https://i.im.ge/2022/11/29/SweNQx.dsfd.png" alt="" class="betActiveImg" />
              <div class="mdlsc">
                <button class="opnBtn">
                  <div class="btnimg">
                    <img src="https://i.im.ge/2022/11/29/Swem9L.prctg.png" alt="" />
                    <span class="chipMoney"></span>
                  </div>
                </button>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          
          <!-- ALL PAIR -->
          <div class="col-4 SlctBetActvCls">
            <div class="snglimg mngrd">
              <img src="https://i.im.ge/2022/11/29/SwetxJ.allpair.png" alt="" class="betActiveImg" />
              <div class="mdlsc">
                <button class="opnBtn">
                  <div class="btnimg">
                    <img src="https://i.im.ge/2022/11/29/Swem9L.prctg.png" alt="" />
                    <span class="chipMoney"></span>
                  </div>
                </button>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          
          
          <!-- ALPHABET PAIR -->
          <div class="col-4 SlctBetActvCls">
            <div class="snglimg mngrd">
              <img src="https://i.im.ge/2022/11/29/SweCqS.alphabet.png" alt="" class="betActiveImg" />
              <div class="mdlsc">
                <button class="opnBtn">
                  <div class="btnimg">
                    <img src="https://i.im.ge/2022/11/29/Swem9L.prctg.png" alt="" />
                    <span class="chipMoney"></span>
                  </div>
                </button>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          
          
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="coinsc">
      <div class="coin" id="selected-chips"></div>
    </div>
  </section>
</main>
```

Comment: how do I do it like whenever I change the column, the "chipMoney" value will be 1 again. no matter how the value is and again clicking the chips it'll fill the value according to the chips value

Comment: That should be easy enough. Rather than `if( stake )el.querySelector(`span.${css.money}`).textContent=stake;` change to `el.querySelector(`span.${css.money}`).textContent=1;`??